# SVN Restore "Replaced" file with older revision; log doesn't contain any old revisions

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

A past coworker was updating a document and somehow managed to remove all history from the log of the file. I have spent hours trying to figure out how to undo what he did, or even replicate what he did to no avail. Below are some images to give a better idea of what I am trying to do (or undo).

This is what 'show log' displays currently.

[image: This is what 'show log' displays currently]

This is what I am trying to get it to display (used repo-browser).

[image: This is what I am trying to get it to display (used repo-browser)]

At this point I am find manually adding changes that were made to the document, as long as I can get the revision history back. I'll also note that saving the old version doesn't seem to trigger SVN to think that the two files are different. I've been experimenting with some temp files to try to replicate the situation by using switch, merge or what ever other options I can find and nothing is working.

Version Information:

- TortoiseSVN 1.9.7, Build 27907 - 64 Bit , 2017/08/08 19:34:38
- Subversion 1.9.7, -release
- apr 1.5.2
- apr-util 1.5.4
- serf 1.3.9
- OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
- zlib 1.2.8
- SQLite 3.14.1

Answer (score 1):

I ended up resolving the issue, but the revision log numbers were affected.

These are the steps I took:

1. Copied the replaced file to another location.
2. svn-deleted the replaced file, and then committed change.
3. Using repo-browser, found the last modified version of the file before it was replaced, right clicked, selected "Copy to working copy...", saved the file, and then committed.
4. Moved the copy of the replaced file back, overwriting the newly committed file.
5. Committed change, ensuring that the files was "modified".

This means that the revision log has two new additions, and the original commit is not in the log, but the history is at least there now. Below is the new log.

[This is the log after performing the above steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d16pG.png)

If anyone has a better solution, by all means please post it here in case someone else encounters this same issue.